Bluetooth Serial with MAUI (android)
I need to send serial command to a HC-05 Module from a MAUI Android app and get response from the device, but I couldn't find any working example that allow that, founded only BLE plugins; Is there a way?Is it possible Bluetooth Classic (serial) on MAUI for an android app?
